# URL No Longer Exists

Tags: rest-api, rest

I'm getting **"URL No Longer Exists"** when I tried to get `access_token` through vf page by calling method from it.
When I executed this method from anonymous block i'm getting valid response.
Any one suggest me what i miss in this code.
I done all remote site settings.

```java
    public class UserNamePasswordFlow {
        public string result             {set;get;}
        public string access_token       {set;get;}
        
        public  string getData(){
            Http p = new Http();
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            HttpResponse response = new HttpResponse();
            IntegrationUser__c sf = [SELECT Id, Name, password__c, client_id__c, client_secret__c, endpoint__c, method__c, grant_type__c FROM IntegrationUser__c limit 1];
            request.setMethod(sf.method__c);
            request.setEndpoint(sf.endpoint__c);
            string body = 'grant_type='+sf.grant_type__c;
            body = body+'&client_id='+sf.client_id__c;
            body = body+'&client_secret='+sf.client_secret__c;
            body = body+'&username='+sf.Name;
            body = body+'&password='+sf.password__c;
            request.setBody(body);
            response = p.send(request);
            System.debug(body);
            system.debug(response.getBody());
            result = response.getBody();
            
            return result;
        }
      }
```

VfPage

```html
    <apex:page controller="UserNamePasswordFlow" showHeader="false">
        <apex:form>
            <apex:commandButton value="Token" action="{!getData}" />
            {!result}
        </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your error?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is mostly due to a security setting in Salesforce to disable clickjack.
You need to disable the security in Setup -> Security Controls -> Session Setting -> Enable clickjack

Reference:
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000fzlyIAA